# Find where "Debug assertion failed" error occured

Tags: c#, c++, com, native

I have written a C# application that uses a native mfc library as COM component. This program is running on the server machine to monitor some hardware devices. Although most of the time the application is work properly, Sometimes I'm getting "C++ Debug assertion failed" message box.

I want to know how can I debug my application and see the call stack of my source code when the assertion failed error appear. I have my C# app source code, but the problem is the assertion occurred in unmanaged code. When I attached visual studio debugger to the app, nothing appeared when the assertion failed error was raised!

Comment: Trying to debug a program without sources is hard. You are effectively reverse-engineering.

Comment: i have my C# app source code but the problem is the assertion occured in unmanaged code, i have attached visual studio debugger to the app, but nothing appear when assestion failed error raised!

Comment: Well, there's one suggestion: Look up and assert the pre-conditions of the unmanaged code, as far as you can, in your part of the code before calling. If you are lucky, that will work and remove any need for reverse-engineering or re-writing the black-box.

Comment: thanks, can you explain more about the "Look up and assert the pre-conditions of the unmanaged code"?

Comment: It means track down the documentation of the interface you use, and make sure you are using it properly. No idea how I could make it clearer...

Comment: Project + Properties, Debug tab, tick the "Enable native code debugging option".  Set a breakpoint on the C++ code that produces the assert.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can only debug this if you have the source code of the COM component. Once you've opened that project attach the debugger to the process that will call/load the DLL of the COM component.